# Create date from text string in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I want to convert a text string to a `datetime` and then output in a different format. I think i can do this with `date_create_from_format()`, but this doesn't return any detail.

```
$datetime=date_create_from_format( 'Y-m-d.H:i:sP'  , '2020-05-26T11:03:00+00:00' );
$newdatestring=date('g:iA', $datetime);
```

Comment: You may want to look at `strtotime()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try with the following simple code. Note, that if you want to include a literal character in the format, you need to escape it with a backslash (`\`). The result from `date_create_from_format() / DateTime::createFromFormat()` call is a `DateTime` object representing the date and time specified by the time string, so you need to format it appropriately.

Procedural:

```
<?php
$datetime = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', '2020-05-26T11:03:00+03:00');
echo date_format($datetime, 'g:iA');
?>
```

Object-oriented:

```
<?php
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', '2020-05-26T11:03:00+03:00');
echo $datetime->format('g:iA');
?>
```

Output:

```
11:03AM
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple with the DateTime class:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2020-05-26T11:03:00+00:00');

$newdatestring = $datetime->format('g:iA');
```

If necessary, you can also use `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Comment: The code you posted (`$datetime = new DateTime('2020-05-26T11:03:00+00:00'); $newdatestring = $dt->format('g:iA');`) returns errors (`Undefined variable: dt ...` and `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null ...`).